# How to extract dates from a text string?

Tags: r, string, date

Im trying to extract dates from a text string. So far I have had some progress with the `anydate`. My idea is to extract all dates within a text string,to a string separated by a comma, like this:

```
str1 = "08/07/2022 FC 08/15/2022 yusubclavio derecho"
paste0(anydate(str_extract_all(str1, "[[:alnum:]]+[ /]\\d{2}[ /]\\d{4}")[[1]]), collapse = ", ")
[1] "2022-08-07, 2022-08-15"
```

My problems start when date format is DD/MM/YYYY.

```
str1 = "22/08/2022 FC yusubclavio derecho"
paste0(anydate(str_extract_all(str1, "[[:alnum:]]+[ /]\\d{2}[ /]\\d{4}")[[1]]), collapse = ", ")
[1] ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `parse_date` from `parsedate` - it should be able to parse most of the date format, but 2 digit year can be an issue i.e if the '22' should be parsed as 1922 instead of 2022

```
library(parsedate)
as.Date( parse_date(unlist(str_extract_all(str1, "\\d+/\\d+/\\d+"))))
```

-output

```
[1] "2022-08-22" "2022-08-22" "2022-08-07" "2022-08-15"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("08/22/22 FC yusubclavio derecho", "22/08/2022 FC yusubclavio derecho", 
"08/07/2022 FC 08/15/2022 yusubclavio derecho")
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option might be using `scan` + `grep`

```
> grep("^(\\d|/)+$", scan(text = str1, what = "", quiet = TRUE), value = TRUE)
[1] "08/22/22"   "22/08/2022" "08/07/2022" "08/15/2022"
```